# how to move URL configured in NODEJS from windows to linux box

Tags: node.js, mongodb

how to move URL configured in NODEJS with MongoDB from windows server to linux server.
I have not tried anything as i'm new to linux world

Comment: Provide first your solution

Answer (score 0):

- Install Linux
- Install Node (I suggest using NVM)
- Install MongoDB
- unpackage code
- node [path_to_entry_point].js